# Show/hide menus in sidebars depending on the user roles (Laravel/Spatie)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 roles in my application which are `admin` and `former`. For information, the permissions are OK also.

Now, my problem is that if the user `Former` is connected. He can see the  rubric "Admin" , is it possible to keep only the rubric `formers`?

[image]

Do you know where the change is to be made?
I am hesitating between Controller or Middleware?

In my file blade.php I have this:

```
  <li class="px-nav-item">
   @if (!Auth::guest())
   <a href="/admin"><i class="px-nav-icon ion-grid"></i><span class="px-nav-label">Listing admin</span></a>
   @endif
  </li>
  <li class="px-nav-item">
    @if (!Auth::guest())
    <a href="/formers"><i class="px-nav-icon ion-grid"></i><span class="px-nav-label">Listing formers</span></a>
    @endif
  </li>
```

Comment: do you need to hide the sidebar base on user roles isn't it?

Comment: @Theekshana: Yes, I want to hide the sidebar. For example the user `Former` can see only the rubric `Former`  and no `Admin`.

Comment: If so you can do it Laravel blade page. base on the current login user role, you can show hide the sidebar element.

Comment: @Theekshana: I have edited my first message, you think my code is good?

Comment: `@if (!Auth::guest())` this statement evaluate whether user is login or not. If you want to check about login user role this approach will not be suitable.

Comment: @Theekshana: Ok, thank you... I don't see how to do, if you have an idea,  I'm interested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197792/discussion-between-theekshana-and-user11124425).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get current login user roles using `spatie` inbuilt method.

```php
@if(in_array("admin", Auth::user()->roles->toArray()))
//if your login user role is admin show the content here
@endif

@if(in_array("former", Auth::user()->roles->toArray()))
//if your login user role is former show the content here
@endif
```

I did not test this code, hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is writing a `View Composer` to create your menu based on different conditions, in your case based on user information.
As an example, you can have a view composer to create an array of link items and then access that array in your views and build the menu with given link items array:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(
            'layout', 'App\Http\View\Composers\MenuComposer'
        );
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class ProfileComposer
{
    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $menu = [];
        if (!\Auth::guest()) {
          $menu[] = ['link' => '/admin', 'text' => 'Listing admin'];
        }

        if (!\Auth::guest()) {
          $menu[] = ['link' => '/formers', 'text' => 'Listing formers'];
        }

        $view->with('menu', $menu);
    }
}
```

So in your `layout.blade.php` you have access to `$menu` variable

```
@foreach($menu as $link)
<li class="px-nav-item">
   <a href="{{$link['link']}}"><i class="px-nav-icon ion-grid"></i><span class="px-nav-label">{{$link['text']}}</span></a>
</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have edited my first message. I have 3 questions please... 

1) I have edited the file `ViewServiceProvider` and I have added  the function `boot()` 

2) Where I have to create the `ProfileComposer` ??? 

3) I have to create a folder composer in my folder views ??

Comment: @user11124425 1) Was that a question? 2) Based on Laravel documentation a good place for composers is the `app/Http/View/Composer` directory. 3) No you dont need to have any directory related to view composers in your `view` directory. You only need to use variables that provided by your view composer classes in your existing view files.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this in your Laravel blade if you are using [Spatie's Laravel-permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction):

```
@role('admin')
//Show some button
@endrole

@role('former')
//Show some button
@endrole
```